# Set Cookies in apollo server azure functions

Tags: graphql, azure-functions, apollo-server

I am using apollo server in the azure function. I want to set cookies from apollo server azure functions. But it's not working. It doesn't throw any kind of errors.

How do I set cookies in apollo server azure functions? I tried this way but it's not working.

Here is my code

```
import { ApolloServer, gql } from "apollo-server-azure-functions";

import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } from "apollo-server-core";

import { serialize, parse } from "cookie";

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    user: User
  }

  type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
  }
`;

// Provide resolver functions for your schema fields
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user: (parents, args, { request, context }, info) => {
      const cookie = serialize("token", "123", {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000),
        httpOnly: true,
      });

      context.res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie);

      return {
        id: "1",
        name: "John Doe",
        email: "john@example.com",
      };
    },
  },
};

// @ts-ignore
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  debug: true,
  plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true })],
  context: (context) => {
    return context;
  },
});

export default server.createHandler({
  cors: {
    origin: ["*", "https://studio.apollographql.com"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
    allowedHeaders: [
      "access-control-allow-header",
      "access-control-allow-credentials",
      "access-control-allow-origin",
      "content-type",
    ],
  },
});
```

There is no documentation available for apollo server azure functions.

Official repository from apollo server azure functions: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-azure-function-graphql-hello.git

Comment: I do see the issue created in the github repro https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-azure-function-graphql-hello/issues/7 Let me reach out to team for their inout.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the discussion with the team internal and posting the update as updated [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-azure-function-graphql-hello/issues/7).

> After looking at the issue, the infrastructure, and the [announcement from Apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/6032) for this package, I believe Apollo is the correct organization to post this issue because Apollo is providing the server in this sample. It just happens to be running on an Azure Function. Additionally, when I look for a solution on Apollo, it looks like the ApolloServer dependency needs to be swapped out for an Apollo server for express dependency in order to successfully set the cookie.
>
> None of this is great news. I apologize for this.
>
> I believe the sample works in this repo without cookes and doesn't currently include cookies in the code. Moving forward with the Apollo dependency, we will re-evaluate its use based on this feedback.